# Quicker way to include viewport meta tag in 300+ pages

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

Well I made a pretty amateur mistake on a responsive design and didn't include the viewport tag on a few hundred pages meaning the media query's aren't recognised:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

My question is basically, is there any way (instead of manually entering it in each page) to make the design work and use the media query's correctly, something like using an import on the css page maybe?

Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: Open all the files (or batches of them) in Notepad++, then do a Find for the two lines above and below where you want to insert, and replace with those lines, plus the viewport tag. Then learn PHP and do things dynamically :)

Comment: use Find and replace for `folder` in dreamweaver

Comment: Or any other editor that can find and replace in multiple files. Or use SSI for import.

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured out the command for Sublime Text, really handy!